# ShellExecute/Shell etc not doing what I need

Tags: ms-access, vba

Well, I'm sure it's out there but I can't find it..

I want to shell out to a program (from Access VBA) and then wait for it to complete.  There are examples of this using Shell but it seems like with Shell you have to pass the executable and not just the file path/name.  Since this will be used on multiple machines, I can't guarantee what the executable will be on the target machine (eg which pdf viewer is set up) so I want to use the defaults.

I can use Shellexecute to start a file with the default program, but I can't get the window handle to run the wait routines.  Since I need to run multiple external pieces, I need to wait for each one to complete before I launch the next one.

So.  Can anyone help me with an idea of how to get Shell to use the default program or how to get the handle for a Shellexecute window or suggest another API that will do all of the pieces I need?

Thanks -
Alan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following routine  opens a file according to the association in the registry, in *blocking mode*:

```
Sub OpenFileAndWait(fullName As String)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run """" & fullName & """", 3, True
End Sub
```

ps.1: param `3` opens the document in maximized window, and the last param `True` specifies *waiting mode*. Enclosing the file's name with double-quotes eliminates the trouble with names that include "space" for the command interpreter.

ps.2:
There have been lots of discussions about how to achieve this, and the proposed methods take you to complicated APIs such as `ShellExecuteEx`, `CreateProcess`, `WaitForSingleObject` etc, each time with a different set of parameters and deficiencies. None of those methods was complete and satisfactory: some API's (`Shell` or `CreateProcess`) require to specify the executable application, while others (`ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx`) can use file association but alas, they are non-blocking and it is very complicated to get the process handle in order to use `WaitForSingleObject`).

Comment: This is brilliant.  It might be worth adding that `3` = "Activates the window and displays it as a maximized window." [Shell.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: @Andre451 I added some explanation for the parameters. Actually the last parameter is the most relevant to the question, since it specifies *open and wait*. Your link clarifies things further, thanks ;).

Comment: Thanks, A.S.H. Let me experiment with this a little bit and see how it works.  I saw examples of this approach but it was always in a different context and solving a different kind of problem.

One idea that came to me in the night - the ShellExecute does set the called program as the active window, so the way to get the handle is to get the handle of the active window. (Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long). 
Admittedly, a bit of a kludge since it depends on a side effect, but it will work.

Comment: Perfect .  Thanks A.S.H - that did exactly what I wanted and with far less fuss than I was looking at with all the API calls.

Comment: @alanTuring Glad it helped, and thanks for sharing your interesting ideas as well :)